# Whats the correct structure for Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, structure

I have a project in Django called: "my_site", and an app called "blog", I'm trying to render the "index.html" inside the path: my_site/blog/templates/blog/index.html. But keep getting this error:

```
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loadi

ng these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: C:\Users\Ricardo Neto\Dev\Django_Projects\my_site\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Ricardo Neto\Dev\Django_Projects\my_site\blog\templates\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

The view:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

the urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('posts', views.show_all_posts),
    path('posts/<slug:slug>', views.show_post)
]
```

If i move the index.html outside the blog folder, like in this example: my_site/blog/templates/index.html
the code runs and the index.html renders without problem, but i was taught that the correct structure is to create a folder inside templates with the same name of the app.
So could anyone please explain me the way i should structure my files?

Comment: Maybe you should use 'blog\index.html' inside the view function?

Comment: It works, but why should i write 'blog/index.html' in the view to maintain the structure instead of just deleting the blog folder inside templates and using only "blog/templates/index.html" that works without any changes? Is there any reason to have a folder with the same name of the app within the templates folder?

Comment: I wrote a detailed explanation for you, in short: it is used for creating reusable apps due to the Django templates resolution system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django resolves templates relative to the "templates" directory located inside the app directory and chooses the first template across all apps whose name matches. For example, if you have two apps: **blog** and **news** both with templates named "index.html" in the "templates" directory, Django would not be able to choose correctly one of them. To make a distinction you can create a subfolder inside the "templates" directory named after the corresponding application: "blog/templates/blog/index.html" and "news/templates/news/index.html". And after that you can use those templates in the view functions like this: **render(request, 'news/index.html')** and **render(request, 'blog/index.html')**.

You can read about this topic here, check the remark "Template namespacing": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 1):

rather than keeping it within the app. I prefer to keep it under the project file. my_site/templates/app_x/index.html

```
├───accounts
│   
├───django_project
│   
└───templates
    ├───accounts
    └───registration
```

In `settings.py` file update the `DIRS` to the path of the templates folder. Generally, the templates folder is created and kept in the sample directory where `manage.py`.

```
import os

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

If I open separate files under `templates`, I render them as `folder_name/index.html`, otherwise directly as `index.html`.

Comment: I'm not prepared to say this is wrong, but I don't think I can say it's 100% right. Like it might work, but I think var211's answer is supposed to be "the proper way".

Comment: @Shmack, yes, i agree with you :)